# R how to take statistics of repeated names

Tags: r, statistics, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with cases of use in a same area, so I need to take the maximum, the minimum and the average of this. I show a explicit exemple here:

```
area     Case
  5        A
  51       X
  5        B
  51       Y
  5        C
  5        D
```

And I need this:

```
Max=4(area 5), min=2(area 51), average =3((4+2)ocurrences/(2)areas
```

So basically, I need a way to extract Statistics from occurrences of the area field.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
tbl1 <- table(df1$area)
c(max(tbl1), min(tbl1), mean(tbl1))
#[1] 4 2 3
```

Or in a compact way

```
c(range(tbl1), mean(tbl1))
#[1] 2 4 3
```

Comment: I'm testing it right now, thanks, I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!